# Excel - Shift starting column right by x

Tags: excel

In excel I have a dataset. This represents how much stock of 2 products is sold in the first, second, third, etc... month of the product being on the shelves (starts in A1):

```
Month       1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11 12
Product 1   3  5  2  1  6  1  2  4  7  2   1  5 
Product 2   2  1  5  6  2  8  2  1  2  3   4  9
```

However, the first product sales do not always occur in month 1. They occur in month X. Is there a way (not VBA or copy and paste) of shifting the entries right by 'x' so they align with the month.

Example for data above

```
Product 1 starts in month 2
Product 2 starts in month 5

Month       1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10  11 12
Product 1   0  3  5  2  1  6  1  2  4  7   2   1  5 
Product 2   0  0  0  0  2  1  5  6  2  8   2   1  2  3   4  9    

*0 not required (great if possible), but more for illustration
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a simple example that does the same job. The shown formula is copied over the shown cells in the row of new data. (The number '2' in the formula refers to the column number of the starting data cell which is column B, hence 2.)

[image]